# Fetching Google Analytics data

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api

I need to fetch web traffic data from Google Analytics for further analysis.

I've looked into Kaggle datasets to find what kind of web traffic data exists in general.
I found a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mkechinov/ecommerce-behavior-data-from-multi-category-store) with a structure that is more or less similar to what I need:
[image]

I also already looked at the [Google API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py), and managed to fetch report data by using the View Id. I need "more raw data" though.

How can I fetch similar data like the sample above from Google Analytics, containing

- timestamp
- url
- session_id
- time on page

I need to access the free version of Google Analytics and not the 150k p.a. one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the metric names (as sometimes they differ from the names GA uses on their platform) you may use the [metrics and dimensions explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/).

Timetamp - ga:dateHourMinute
Url - ga:pagePath
Time on page - ga:timeOnPage

When it comes to session_id you will need to use the [user activity report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/user-reporting) rather than the regular report. This allows downloading all user activity on the website - pageviews, and events.